# TrueCrypt - Recover file from encrypted container using offsets

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, truecrypt

So I had a drive that I had fully encrypted using TrueCrypt that, thanks to having multiple distractions during the Windows 7 install process, I mistakenly managed to format. There was only one file on this drive: a TrueCrypt container which was nearly the size of the drive.

Before anyone says anything, a TrueCrypt file will not be found by any file recovery program as it appears as nothing but random data.

Fortunately, I was able to restore the TC header from the backup header and was able to mount the drive. Unfortunately, all traces of the filesystem are gone. Normally this would be the point at which one gives up, but thanks to having made a similar drive/container setup on an identical disk, I was able to figure out where the offsets for the container on the formatted disk would be.

Using WinHex, I have copied out a small portion of the container to confirm that it is there and that it works (which it is and does). However, the full size of the container is 928GB. Copying this file to a new file will take several days of non-stop computing. I need something that will either be quicker or at least is interruptable.

My question then is: can I create a new NTFS filesystem then populate the MFT with the single file record using the offsets?

Comment: NOTE: Truecyrpt is no longer a maintained and supported product.

Comment: @mdpc Yes, but this has nothing to do with TrueCrypt and was merely a product used before the problem was ever set into motion. Everything TrueCrypt related I need no assistance with.